# Firefox prints less pages than chrome - why?

Tags: html, css

when I visit this page on Chrome:

https://www.rubyrange.com/shop/adventure-tours/adventure-van-tours/from-the-rockies-to-alaska-go-wild-calgary-whitehorse/

I can print 6 pages. When I visit this page on Firefox I can print 3 pages and it seems that pages 3,4,5 are missing.

Anybody has an idea what is wrong in the print css here?

```
/* Print Style Sheet */
@media print {

    * {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;   /* Chrome, Safari */
        color-adjust: exact !important;                 /*Firefox*/
    }


    @page {
           /*size: auto;
           margin: 0;*/
    }

    body {
        /*margin: 10mm;*/
    }

    .site-inner {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
    }

    .header-image .wrap > a {
        top: 0;
    }

    .related.products,
    .top-bar,
    .header-bar-wrapper,
    .nav-primary,
    .ruby-booking-wrapper,
    .envira-gallery-position-overlay,
    .tours-legend,
    .tours-media-headline--gallery,
    .envira-gallery-wrap {
        display: none;
    }

    a[href]:after {
      display: none;
      visibility: hidden;
   }

   .product .entry-summary {
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        font-size: 1.3rem;
   }

   .tours-summary-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
   }

   .tours-teaser-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        padding-left: 0;
   }

   .tours-media-wrapper {
        display: none;
   }

   .woocommerce-Tabs-panel {
    display: block !important;
   }

    .tours-available-dates {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .single-product .ruby-print-box {
      display: none;
    }
}
```